# how split a string by a word

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the next string

```
string example="This is a string and i want to split by [this], it's posible?";
```

Is there any method that allows me to split the string if it finds certain word or string, such as "[this]" or "split"

```
string splitter="[this]";
string1="This is a string and i want to split by ";
string2="[this], it's posible?";
```

or in the other example:

```
    string splitter="split";
    string1="This is a string and i want to split ";
    string2="by [this], it's posible?";
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: string.Split()...........an amazingly simple and quick search away....

Comment: For "the best way" question please show "inferior" why you have now and give concrete criteria for "better". I.e. for performance it is often better not to create new strings at all and use custom indexed sub-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.Split`:

```
string[] splitted = example.Split(new[] { splitter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you want to get rid of whitechars in splitted parts (especially around the splitter in input example):

```
string[] splitted = example.Split(new[] { splitter }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                           .Select(value => value.Trim())
                           .ToArray();
```